# Create, Unable to get logged in user id and name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently using .NET Framework 4.5.1, I do not understand why 'name' seem to always not be present. I have tried

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 
User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

Still I am getting the following compile time error stating on `User` that It **does not contain in the current context?**

Here is my create code

```
public void CreateRecord(SampleDataModel Rec)
{

    DefaultConnection ent = new DefaultConnection();

    SampleData dbRec = new SampleData();

    dbRec.CreatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserName(); // <---- CAUSING ERROR

    dbRec.CurrentOwner = Rec.CurrentOwner;
    dbRec.DateOfBirth = Rec.DateOfBirth;
    ent.SampleData.Add(dbRec);
    ent.SaveChanges();
    SampleData DummyObject = new SampleData();

    CreateAuditTrail(AuditActionType.Create, dbRec.ID, DummyObject, dbRec);

}
```

Comment: please try with 'User.Identity.Name'

Comment: Are you getting a compile or runtime error?

Comment: @YogeshGautam sadly User.Identity.Name doesn't work

Comment: @RandRandom I get the red-line under 'Name'

Comment: Do you get UserId from the identity? If not, there could be a possibility that your user hasn't signed in properly.

Comment: @user869375 Hello! I do get the Userid from the identity

Comment: Are you `using System.Web;` and have you tried `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `User` is a Member of the `Page` class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.user

So if your class, you are trying the get the `User` member doesn't derive from `Page` you cannot access it by simply writing `User`.

For example if it doesnt look like this:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
```

In this case you will have to use the more "direct" method and use

`HttpContext.Current.User` instead of only `User`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.user

So change your line from

```
dbRec.CreatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserName();
```

to

```
dbRec.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName();
```

And add the namespace

```
using System.Web;
```

Comment: Wow simply WOW Million Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that Anonymous Authentication is enabled for the application. Allow Windows (if it is in a domain) and disable Anonymous authentication.

In Visual Studio, open project properies

[image]

In IIS

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time! but that seem not to be the issue

Comment: I learnt something new! but unfortunatly I all my authentication settings are alright

Comment: @husky - notice that he is talking about a compile time error - not an error while running the application

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is simply because your "User" isn't signed in.

Are you sure you have an authentification method ? (Usually a form.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time! but that seem not to be the issue

Comment: @FlorianReiss - notice that he is talking about a compile time error - not an error while running the application